# phonegap app: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, cordova, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to a remote database from my phonegap app.

I'm using an example script I found, but it's not working, as I keep getting `require is not defined` error.

Here's my code (it's inside a  tag):

```
  var Client = require('mysql').Client;
  var client = new Client(); 
  client.host ='1**.**.**.**8:****';
  client.user = '*****';
  client.password = '*****************';
  console.log("connecting...");
  client.connect(function(err, results) {
      if (err) {
          console.log("ERROR: " + err.message);
          throw err;
      }
      console.log("connected.");
      clientConnected(client);
  });

  clientConnected = function(client)
  {
    tableHasData(client);
  }           


  tableHasData = function(client)
  {
      client.query(
          'SELECT * FROM test_db.Users LIMIT 0,10',
          // you can keep this function anonymous
          function (err, results, fields) {
              if (err) {
                  console.log("ERROR: " + err.message);
                  throw err;
              }
              console.log("Got "+results.length+" Rows:");
              for(var i in results){
                console.log(results[i]); 
                console.log('\n');

                //console.log("The meta data about the columns:");
                //console.log(fields);     
              }
              client.end();
          });
  };
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using nodeJS code that can't be run on Cordova. This must be run with [node](http://nodejs.org/).

What you need to do is create a server (where you will run your code with nodeJS) and expose your data through an API for the client (your Cordova app) to come and fetch them. (Use AJAX requests)

Comment: Is there no way I can do it without programming in the server?

Comment: Querying your database like that ? No, you won't be able to do it on a Cordova app...